# Apache Passenger error : Unexpected error in mod_passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I recently washed my **/tmp** and I didn't know that it has some required files for phusion passenger. Now my passenger looking for files which are not there now. I tried running **passenger-install-apache2-module** to get files needed to apache2. But no luck it did not get the files in /tmp. Is there any way to get those files back??

I am getting following error:

```
Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot connect to Unix socket '/tmp/passenger.1.0.1144/generation-0/socket': No such file or directory (2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did following step and it worked:

```
gem install passenger
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now I checked /tmp files required for passenger are there then I did:

```
rvmsudo  passenger-install-apache2-module
```